# echoing only part of an array outside of array

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I'm not sure how to word the question. I'm not an expert on PHP. I'm trying to edit a hotspot plugin. I have this code

```
function ult_hotspot_items_callback( $atts, $content = null ){
       global $hotspot_icon, $hotspot_icon_bg_color, $hotspot_icon_color, $hotspot_icon_size;

        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'hotspot_content'                   => '',
            'hotspot_label'                     => '',
            'hotspot_position'                  => '0,0',
            'tooltip_content'                   => '',
            'tooltip_width'                     => '300',
            'tooltip_padding'                   => '',
            'tooltip_position'                  => '',
            "icon_type"                         => '',
            'icon'                              => 'Defaults-map-marker',
            'icon_color'                        => '',
            'icon_style'                        => '',
            'icon_color_bg'                     => '',
            'icon_border_style'                 => '',
            'icon_color_border'                 => '',
            'icon_border_size'                  => '',
            'icon_border_radius'                => '',
            'icon_border_spacing'               => '',
            'icon_img'                          => '',
            'img_width'                         => '60',
            'link_style'                        => '',
            'icon_link'                         => '',
            'icon_size'                         => '',
            "alignment"                         =>  "center",
            'tooltip_trigger'                   => '',
            'tooltip_animation'                 => '',
            'tooltip_continuous_animation'      => '',
            'glow_color'                        => '',
            'enable_bubble_arrow'               => 'on',
            'tooltip_custom_bg_color'           => '#fff',
            'tooltip_custom_color'              => '#4c4c4c',
            'tooltip_font'                      => '',
            'tooltip_font_style'                => '',
            'tooltip_font_size'                 => '',
            'tooltip_font_line_height'          => '',
            'tooltip_custom_border_size'        => '',
            'tooltip_align'                     => '',
        ), $atts )  );
```

I want to refference/call/echo just the "'tooltip_content'" results of that array outside of that array elsewhere on the page. How do I go about doing that?

Thank you.

Unfortunately there is a character limit I tried to share all the page code but it won't let me

Comment: It is impossible to answer that question with what you have provided. As it stands that array is only defined inside the function, and cannot be accessed outside of it.

Comment: okay then can I create another variable referencing that array or duplicating it and just getting the info from tooltip_content?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want, because the PHP code you included has a hard-coded value for `tooltip_content`, i.e. blank. It would only be useful if it were dynamic. NB: You don't need to share all your code, only the essential parts. For instance, we don't need to know about the 30+ other key/values of that array.

Comment: so the plugin on the back end lets you create these little tips. called tool tips. It places them on parts of an image when you hover over them they pop up. I want to also echo/print those same tooltips the user puts in else where on the page for help with mobile support. That's what I'm trying to do. The only reference I've found for calling that is $content which shows up everything inc icons. All I need is the physical content and thats the only reference to it in that array under tooltip_content

Comment: I still don't understand how you get hard-coded PHP on the one hand, and say they are user input on the other hand. That is a contradiction. Is what you shared as code *really* the code?

Comment: Also, Do you have the *shortcode_atts* function definition? That could maybe shed some light on this question. Maybe the literal array in your code is just a set of *default* values -- not the actual values you need.

Comment: it's a wordpress plugin. This is the file that edits the output. shortcode_atts is a wordpress refference if that's what you mean? I'm starting to think its I've uploaded all the code here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/780d456ac7a2d1b31731ed235a4d274ac27a6eea

Comment: Okay you're right, it's not the tooltip_content. I'm onto something with $hotspot_content = $content;
   
   $content = wpb_js_remove_wpautop($content, true);
   
    $hotspot_content = $content;
   $tip = esc_html( str_replace('"', '\'', $hotspot_content ));
   
   $tool = '<li>' . $tip . '</li>';
   $output = '<div>
  <div><ul>' . $tool . '</ul></div></div>';

Answer (score 0):

As your code is not quite clear, but it seems to me that you are set a value `$tooltip_content`. If so, the Yes, As you defined it as global, so it will available out side the function.

Comment: can you give an example on how i would write that up?

Comment: As your function is not clear but here is an simple example:  function callbackfun( ){
       global   $tooltip_content;
  $tooltip_content = 'dfgfhfgh';
        
   echo $tooltip_content ;
}

callbackfun( $atts, $content = null );
 echo  ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>".$tooltip_content ;

Comment: I don't see how the full function should matter at all. All I need to do is display the tooltips written in the wordpress backend. Which I've narrowed it down to that array 'tooltip_content' - how can i refference or even create a new array/variable to display that info? There is a character limit in posting it won't let me share the full function

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. it had nothing to do with the array at all. You guys were right. I'm really sorry for such a confusing post. Like I said I'm no php expert. What I needed was the variable $content or $hotspot_content. When I used that it was rendering the content and the added html tags and styling because of an output further down the page. So it was pretty much adding `<ul><li>` to the output and then calling it

`$tip_content = $content;
$output = '<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  mobile"><div class="wpb_wrapper"><ul>' . strip_tags ($tip_content, '<li>') . "</ul></div></div>";`

and the refference to the content was called further down the page

```
if($link_style == 'link'){
            $output .= "   <a data-link_style='simple' class='ult-tooltip ult-tooltipstered ult-hotspot-tooltip' href='".$url."' ".$link_title." ".$target." data-status='hide'>";
            $output .= $icon_inline;
            $output .= "  </a>";
        } else {
            $output .= "   <a data-link_style='tootip' ".$data." class='ult-tooltip ult-tooltipstered ult-hotspot-tooltip' href='#' data-status='show'>";
                $output .= $icon_inline;
                $output .= "<span class='hotspot-tooltip-content'><ul><li>".esc_html( str_replace('"', '\'', $hotspot_content ) )."</li></ul></span>";
            $output .= "  </a>";
        }

        $output .= " </div><!-- ICON WRAP -->";

        $output .= $glow;

        $output .= "</div>";
        return $output;
    }
```

I couldn't over ride the styles but like I said I just added the list to them and when calling them seperately on the page I just used the `strip_tags ($tip_content, '<li>')` strip_tags function to stop it outputting all the other code except for listing